# Sometimes hosts on AWS do not resolve

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-php-sdk

With a large number of simultaneous queries generated by the AWS SDK for PHP, errors occur (but not every time)

```
{" message ":" Error executing \ "ListObjects \" on \ "https: \ / \ / s3-name.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com \ /? prefix = text2F5067% 2F & encoding-type = url \ "; AWS HTTP error: cURL error 6: (see https: \ / \ / curl.haxx.se \ / libcurl \ / c \ /libcurl-errors.html) "}
```

This also happens with third-party services - ie SMTP server.
On Amazon I use alb + ec2 + rds + s3 resources.

Comment: What is the version of the PHP SDK and PHP version?

Comment: @MuzaffarShaikh - SDK - 1.0.29 and PHP - 7.3.6

Comment: Can you add the code you are using?